# App Engine Python: Templates not rendering properly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

I don't understand what could be wrong with this code for rendering pages.

```
def post(self):
        acct = self.request.get('account')
        pw = self.request.get('password')

        que = db.Query(User)
        que = que.filter('account =', acct)
        que = que.filter('password =', pw)
        results = que.fetch(limit = 1)

        values = { }
        newval = dict(values)
        newval['path'] = self.request.path

        if len(results) > 0:
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/sites.htm')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {}))
```

I call it from a login form located on a page named **"loginscreen.htm"**.
When the application reaches this part of the code:

```
if len(results) > 0:
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/sites.htm')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {}))
```

and attempts to redirect to **'sites.htm'**, the page 'sites.htm' is correctly displayed but in the address bar it's still showing:

**'http://localhost:8080/login'** ("/login" routes incoming request from "loginscreen.htm") when **'http://localhost:8080/sites.htm'** should 
be shown instead.

The main problem with this is that if I reload the page, the *"Confirm Form Resubmission"* dialog appears allowing users to submit the form again.
But if I replace

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/sites.htm')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {}))
```

by

```
self.redirect('sites.htm')
```

the address bar displays **'http://localhost:8080/sites.htm'** correctly.

So what is wrong with the code?

Sorry if I made this question sound more complicated than it should be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is a misunderstanding here:

> call it from a login form located on a page named "loginscreen.htm".
>   When the application reaches this part of the code:

```
if len(results) > 0:
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/sites.htm')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {}))
```

> and attempts to redirect to 'sites.htm', the page 'sites.htm' is
>   correctly displayed but in the address bar it's still showing:

That code doesn't do anything like a redirect -- all it does is tell AppEngine to respond to that login attempt by rendering out the template at `sites.htm` in response to the POST request. If you want to redirect, you need to do that explicitly (as you appear to have already tried).